# Azure DevOps advice for a project involving Azure Data Factory and Azure SQL Database

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I'm about to embark on a data warehouse project involving Azure SQL database and Azure Data Factory.  I'm looking for some guidance on whether to use a GIT repository for each or a single repository for both, and if so what sort of branching strategy would be suitable.  Ideally, releases for both would be be unified in a single release pipeline.  Only a single database/adf developer will be involved at the outset and I want to keep their workflow as straight forward as possible.  I have no problems finding advice for an Azure DevOps project containing ADF or Azure SQL DB but nothing for a combination of the two.  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Azure DevOps supports check out multiple repositories in your pipeline. By using multiple `checkout` steps in your pipeline, you can fetch and check out other repositories in addition to the one you use to store your YAML pipeline. So if you want to use a GIT repository for each project, it would be OK.

```
steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: git://MyProject/MyRepo # Azure Repos Git repository in the same organization
```

More details, you can refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?